# Timing the visibility time of an object

Tags: javascript, timer, viewport, onscroll

I want know if an object (at least 50%) is visible or not. That's what I did with this code.

I would like to improve my code to know how long this object has been visible. I don't know how to take the Date when it arrives in the Viewport and take the Date when it's no longer visible.

My code returns in the console all 'true' and 'false' at each scroll, so, is it possible to take date at the first 'true' and take a new Date when it's become 'false' ?

Thanks in advance,

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<img id="image_test" width="300" height="200" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/23/23656.svg" alt="100" />
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
  var isInViewport = function (elem) {
      var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
      return (
         bounding.top >= -0.5 * elem.height &&
         bounding.left >= 0 &&
         bounding.bottom <= 1.15 * (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && 
         bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
      );
  };
  
  var player = document.getElementById('image_test');
  
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
   canUserSeeIt = isInViewport(player);
   console.log(canUserSeeIt);
  }, false);

};  
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code modified will tell:

- For how long the object has been visible in milliseconds
- When the object becomed invisible

  ```
  window.onload = function() {
      var start = new Date();
      var stillVisible = true;
      var isInViewport = function (elem) {
          var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
          return (
          bounding.top >= -0.5 * elem.height &&
          bounding.left >= 0 &&
          bounding.bottom <= 1.15 * (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && 
          bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
          );
      };

      var player = document.getElementById('image_test');

      window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
          canUserSeeIt = isInViewport(player);
          if (stillVisible && !canUserSeeIt){
            var now = new Date(); // Becomed invisible
            stillVisible = false;
            var visibleTime = now - start; // How long has been visible
            console.log(now, visibleTime);
          }
          console.log(canUserSeeIt);
      }, false);
  ```

  };

https://jsbin.com/wuqegedeyo/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I try it it only give me the Date at my first scroll, and so on not when the picture is visible and not at all when it become invisible. It don't tell me how long it has been shown. Here I think it take the date when the screen is on and not when the object is visible, I'll try to modify it a little :)